# Local variable reference to object property overhead in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is it a bad practice to use a local variable as reference to an object property instead of the property itself?

```
function Apple(){
  this.type = 'green appale';
}

Apple.prototype.slice = function(){
  //Does this create a noticeable overhead?
  var type = this.type;

  //slicing action

}
```

Comment: It's *probably* an extremely small *improvement*, but in this day and age it's pointless to second-guess the increasingly sophisticated JavaScript runtimes of the world.

Comment: There isn't anything necessarily wrong with it. Just note that `type` is a *copy* of `this.type`, not a reference to it. Each can be modified without affecting the other.

Comment: It's only a copy because a string is immutable in JS. If `this.type` was an object or an array then it would be a reference.

Comment: @Sukima It's still a copy with objects, but the value being copied is a reference. Modifying one of the variables directly still won't affect the other, but you can modify the object itself and see the change from both variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is both yes and no. From a performance stand point don't worry about it. This is a cake walk compared to other performance issues. Besides the rule of thumb is to write code for readability and only optimize when you need to through profiling after the fact. Don't pre optimize.

As for the caveats… If the value you are *saving* as an immutable value (string, int, boolean) then your are 100% safe do do this. If it is an object or array then your need to know that it is a reference and changes will affect the *original* variable as well. And finally if it is a function then you have to be aware that you will loose it's **context** in the code example above.

```
function foo() {}

var bar = foo; // Context is irrelevant.

function foo() {
  this.baz = 'foobar';
}

var bar = foo; // You must provide a context or `this` becomes `window`.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am aware that the context of a funtion is the caller. I imagined that the performance difference would not be huge bust still thought I could be missing something.

Comment: You not missing anything. There might be a tiny hit to memory but again it's a grain of sand compared to the size of the earth. Focus on the readability of the code first and don't fret over the grains of sand. Code for humans first.